# Can a Kafka consumer removed from group rejoin

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible for a Kafka consumer who was removed from a consumer group due session time out to rejoin the group?

Answer (score 1):

Consumers maintain Partition ownership and group ownership by sending heartbeats to group coordinator.

When a Consumer stops sending heartbeats for few seconds, then group coordinator will decide Consumer as dead and triggers rebalance in this case.

Behavior of Consumer group varies when the consumer comes back later based on Static/Dynamic membership. Coordinator recognizes Consumers based on Consumer Id (Dynamic membership - UUID assigned to Consumer initially by the group coordinator when it joined Consumer group for the first time) or Group instance Id (Static membership - which is configured by users to uniquely identify their consumer instances)

***Consumer with Consumer-Id (Membership-Id or Group instance Id):***

- When the Consumer rejoins the group with its membership information (or) group instance information then rebalance will be triggered and ***the same assignment will be guaranteed in this case***.

***Consumer without Consumer-Id (Membership-Id or Group instance Id):***

- When the Consumer comes back without membership information (or) group instance information, then it will be considered as a new Consumer and assign a new UUID. In this case, ***group coordinator doesn't guarantee that its old assignment will be assigned back***.